# ECS task stops, container exits. Executable file not in $PATH

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have been trying to get my application working - but I keep getting an error:

`Task Stop Reason: Essential container in task exited; Container myapp Status Reason: CannotStartContainerError: API error (400): OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker-compose up\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:9.10.0

COPY / /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
RUN chown -R node:node /myapp

USER node
RUN mkdir /home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=/home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install

USER root
ENV USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        python \
        python-dev \
        python-pip \
        python-setuptools \
    && pip install --upgrade awscli \
    && apt-get clean
```

Now my task definition (`deploy.yaml`) is pretty simple and a part of it is:

```
....
task:
    taskRole: "<role>"
    containerDefinitions:
    - command:
        - "docker-compose up"
...
```

When deploying the app, ECS normally runs `docker run` I assume, while I need `docker-compose up` to start my services (in `docker-compose.yaml`). Where do I run this command, or how do I fix this path?

Comment: At a high level you need to translate your Docker Compose YAML file into ECS task descriptions describing the containers it wants to run.  They do essentially the same job and one can’t run the other.

Comment: you dont need to mention command here. there is no docker compose up in ECS. there task definition in which you mentiion docker image, there is task in which mention task definition and there is service in which u mention task. thats the whole story. docker compose is a command of docker engine not of ECS.
A string array representing the command that the container runs to determine if it is healthy. The string array can start with CMD to execute the command arguments directly,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html

Answer (score 4):

If you look closer to the error message :

```
starting container process caused "exec: \"docker-compose up\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

You notice that Docker is trying to find an executable named "docker-compose up" in PATH. This is probably incorrect,it should have looked for a "docker-compose" executable  (note the missing "[space] up" in exe path).
This is probably caused by a wrong "-command" YML properties.

You should have something like :

```
...
 -command :
    -docker-compose
    -up
```

I experienced the same problem with the ENTRYPOINT command in the Dockerfile :

```
ENTRYPOINT ["command with parameters"]
```

is invalid. You must have

```
ENTRYPOINT ["command", "with", "parameters"]
```